# F# - Save the previous printed text

Tags: f#, functional-programming

So I have a text file containing characters where I let the user read by printing in the console (by reading the file content into a char list and converting it to a string), after that I am trying to let the user change one letter in the char list. However doing so I will have to do a loop and access the variable containing the char list and loop through it and later save it in the same variable (or a new variable) to show the user for approval, if not the user should be able to change a character again by running the same loop.

Though my problem is that I can't find a way to change the variable containing the character list without making the variable mutable. Is there any suggestion for this problem?

```
            while true do            
                Console.Write("\n\nDo you want to change some tokens? press 1 or 2 to end: ")
                let rep = Console.ReadLine() |> int
                if rep = 1 then
                    Console.Write("\n\n Enter the token you will change in the text : ")
                    let user = Console.ReadLine() |> char
                    let k1 = user
                    Console.Write("\n Enter your token you will replace TO : ")
                    let user2 = Console.ReadLine() |> char
                    let k2 = user2
                    let t = finalList
                    let finalList2 = swap t k1 k2
                    let f2 = finalList2 |> charListToString

                    printfn "%s" f2
```

As seen in my code implementation above, I can only change the list once and if the loop runs again it will loose the first value which was changed before.

Answer (score 2):

Not claiming that this is the best solution, but based on your question I think this is what you are trying to achieve; a simple find and replace character by character in a string?

Here is a solution that uses a recursive function and an internal pattern match for the key the user presses. It should get you started, put it into an .fsx file and call fsc on the commandline on the fsx file, then you can call the resulting exe and see what it does.

```
open System

let rec change ( data : string ) =
  printfn "\n1 to make changes or 2 to quit"
  let keyPressed = Console.ReadKey() 
  match keyPressed.KeyChar with
  | '1' -> 
    printfn "\nEnter the character in the string you want to change:"
    let changeChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar
    printfn "\nEnter the character to change to:"
    let changeTo = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar
    let newData = data.ToCharArray() |> Array.map ( fun c -> if c = changeChar then changeTo else c ) |> String
    printfn "\n%s\n" newData
    change newData
  | '2' -> data
  | _ -> change data

[<EntryPoint>]
let Main args =
  printfn "\n%s\n" <| change "abc"

  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but I already figured this and my problem is that after the user has changed the character once in the list, the second time the user should be able to continue to change the changed list as like decryption.

Comment: I am trying to do decryption where I am using list of tokens and characters. It should be able for the user to change all tokens and characters in the file by entering so much tries he need until the text file is clearly readable. I have already figured all functions and inputs, but the problem is that when the user change a character in the first try then in second try it will restore the first changed character and change a new one. But I want that the user can continue and change remaining characters and update the new result in the console.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's exactly what Mr. Mr.'s solution does. Have you tried running it?